# Storing video locally and playing using HTML5 video tag?

Tags: html, html5-video, html5-appcache

We are building a content delivery system, where users can upload videos and view (playback) the uploaded videos on their browser.

We need to provide offline support on viewing side. The videos files should get downloaded to the local storage and the HTML5 video tag should point to the downloaded video.

Has any one tried this before, Is this possible? what are the major challenges? any inputs on this is really appreciated.

Comment: Local storage as in a normal download to a normal folder as a normal file? Or do you mean localStorage API that allows data to be stored with the browser? If you meant the latter, I think it's limited to 5MB.

Comment: I meant normal folder and files.